# User Profile - MultiloginAccounts - Claims: Forms Based Auth and Windows

Tags: user-profile-service, claims-based-auth, user-profile-property

In SharePoint 2010, I'm using Forms Based Auth with the LDAP role and membership providers.  I have the SPS-ClaimID mapped properly so the Forms Based Profile is sync/mapped to the AD Profile.

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to handle other Web Applications in the farm that may have Classic or Claims/Windows auth.  I'd like those Web Apps to use the same User Profile (it is the same underlying AD account).

I stumbled across the MultiloginAccounts property - but it looks like this is read only and is intended for a multi-forest setup.  In theory I was wondering if I could use the BCS to map to the "Source Object Distinguished Name" myself (assuming that property somehow influences the MultiLoginAccounts property).

Does anyone else have this scenario?  Web App with Forms (LDAP) and Web App(s) with Windows (Claims and Classic).

All ideas are appreciated

Comment: I have the same issue...
Dead end...
The only thing that is possible soution is to use custom claims provider...
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any reference material to the custom claims provider solution?